# Magento Autoload.php cannot find other PHP scripts

Tags: magento, zend-framework, permissions

I keep getting this kind of error since I moved Magento from my server to clients server:

```
exception 'Zend_Validate_Exception' with message 'Validate class not found from basename 'NotEmpty'' in /lib/Zend/Validate.php:244
```

Caused by:

```
Warning: include(NotEmpty.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

This one I get when I try to finish my order.

I got one similar yesterday when trying to create an attribute.

```
Warning: include(StringLength.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I checked for permissions and all the files referred by the error have 777 and all the folders from root to those files have also 777.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I followed the hint from the comments and I managed to find the path of the file causing the error. The NotEmpty.php is called from the root of Magento though it should have been in /lib/Zend/Validate/.

Any idea how to get the right path?

Comment: Open the file `app/Mage.php`, search for `Varien_Autoload::register()`, insert `var_dump(get_include_path()); exit;` before that line and run again. Does the output contain an existing and accessible path to the `lib` folder?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I understand the logic but I get this page when going to Checkout and that function gets called a few times before it gets to the point where the error appears. This way, the script dies before getting to the error and the output is: string(84) "//app/code/local://app/code/community://app/code/core://lib:.:/:/usr/local/php/pear5"

Comment: I tried to trigger the var_dump only when it loads the file containing "NotEmpty". It doesn't stop that early anymore, I get to the last step of Checkout and when I press the last button and expect to see the path causing the error I get a Javascript alert: There was an error processing your order. Please contact support or try again later. So, I'm not able to see the path.

Comment: You can't see the output on screen because of the JS part of Magento. Using developer tools of your browser (e.g. Firebug), or a web proxy like http://fiddler2.com/ you can see the `var_dump()` output of every HTTP(S) response.

Comment: I wrote it to a file and found out the path. I edited the original question and added my new one. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Just to be sure: you wrote output is `//lib`. If it's **really** `//lib` then it's wrong, because `//lib` effectively points to the `/lib` folder, which is something completely different than `/path/to/my/magento/lib`.

Comment: Those outputs are irrelevant and wrong. Sorry. I added to my initial question that my output is just NotEmpty.php instead of Zend/Validate/NotEmpty.php . Any ideea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use the Magento compiler? If so, does recompiling help?

Comment: I wasn't using it. I enabled it, recompiled, disabled and same result.